# Code-based Spring Security Configuration

Tags: spring-security, spring-java-config

I am trying to use Spring Security framework with a code-based configuration and I am following [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example) tutorial.

I have the following code in my initializer for the filter:

```java
FilterRegistration.Dynamic springSecurity = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy());
springSecurity.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null,true,"/*");
```

I think this is correct but I don't know how to implement the `spring-security.xml` like a bean in the `@Configuration` class.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update**

There was a project that provided this: ["Spring Security Java Config"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-javaconfig/). It was merged into [spring-security-config](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.springframework.security%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spring-security-config%22) on December 16th, 2013.

From the [`README.MD`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-javaconfig/):

> The Spring Security Java configuration can now be found in spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE+ as part of the Spring Security distribution.

---

**Original**

There currently is no easy way to do Spring Security configuration with Java configuration. You must know what the namespace does behind the scenes making it difficult and error prone. For this reason, I would recommend sticking with the Spring Security namespace configuration.

If you really want to do java configuration you can define all the beans manually. To do this you will need to understand the namespace configuration. The first place to look would be Luke blog post [Behind the Spring Security namespace](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/03/06/behind-the-spring-security-namespace/). If you get stuck I would refer to the source code of [HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/http/HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java)

Last if you would like to be on extremely (unsupported) bleeding edge, you might consider the Spring Security Scala config project. Note that this project is a side project and has not been officially released (nor do I know of any plans to officially release it at this time). You can read details about it on the [Spring Security Configuration with Scala](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/08/01/spring-security-configuration-with-scala/) blog post. This also details out why there is not Java configuration for Spring Security. You might also find the last portion of [Getting Started with Spring Security 3.1](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Spring-Security-3-1) useful as it demos the use of the Spring Security scala configuration.

Comment: Thank you. The Behind the Spring Security namespace tutorial is helping me to understand that using code-based Spring Security configuration is not viable. A lot of beans are created by the framework so it is useless to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I recently scratched my own itch; being able to instantiate a Security Filter programmatically. So I put together what I call "summer security". It's a rudimentary replacement for Spring Security. If you only need sessions, form login/logout and http basic auth it could do the trick for you.

https://github.com/hencjo/summer-security

It's in Maven Central.