# Spring Security - Java Based Configuration AuthenticationManager and Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've updated my spring security to **3.2** to be able to use Java based annotations to configure the project, without need to have an XML.

I almost configure all things, but there is 2 issues I didn't (and don't know how) to configure.

1. How can I configure the `Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint`?
2. How can I configure my **custom** `AuthenticationManager`?

   ```
    <security:http entry-point-ref="entryPoint" >
            ...
    </security:http>

    <bean id="entryPoint"  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" />

    <security:authentication-manager alias="myAuthenticationManagerImpl" />
   ```

Here is my custom authentication class:

```
@Service ("authenticationManager")
public class AuthenticationManagerImpl implements AuthenticationManager {
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is something in the works to address this but as it currently stands there is no way of doing this through annotations. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303894/spring-annotation-equivalent-of-securityauthentication-manager-and-securitygl) seems to seeking the same answer. The standalone project in the works is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-javaconfig/) and apparently they are merging it into spring security 3.2.X sometime in the near future.